# What does おばあちゃん子 / お兄ちゃん子 mean about a kid's personality ? (MC is talking about his little sisters)

Tags: meaning, manga

When reading I saw these terms but don't understand. Many thanks if someone can explain those to me!

> 小さい頃から親代わりに面倒を見てきたせいか、**おばあちゃん子ならぬお兄ちゃん子になってしまったようだ。​**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

デジタル大辞泉 has the following entry for [ばあちゃんこ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%A5%96%E6%AF%8D%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E5%AD%90/#jn-291698) (which I think is rarer than おばあちゃんこ)

> 家族のなかで、特に祖母のことが好きな子。または、特に祖母にかわいがられている子。おばあちゃん子。

It means kids who like Grandmother most. Sometimes it is used also in the sense that the kid is brought up mostly by Grandmother rather than (busy) parents.

Similarly お兄ちゃん子 should mean the kid likes the brother very much, more than parents.

Comment: so she's like a brocon sister  ?

Comment: @casualreader To an extent, yes. But ブラコン connotates loving brother as a man while お兄ちゃん子 simply means liking him a lot.